# Failed to resolve entry for package "appwrite". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, appwrite

Was working on the react app and used `appwrite` as my backend but it is giving me the following error;

** Failed to resolve entry for package "appwrite". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH9xR.png)

All I have done in the file which referred by the error (`auth.js`) is used some appwrite function for creating authorization. Here is the code below for that file,

```
\`import conf from './config';
import { Client, Account, ID } from "appwrite";

export class AuthService {

    client = new Client();
    Account;
    
    constructor() {
        this.client
            .setEndpoint(conf.appwriteURL)
            .setProject(conf.projectID);
    
        this.Account = new Account(this.client)
    }
    
    async createAccount({ email, password, name }) {
        try {
    
            const userAccount = await this.Account.create(ID.unique(), email, password, name);
    
            if (userAccount) {
                // call other methd
                return this.login(email, password);
            }
            else {
                return userAccount;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Appwrite error: createAccount() :: ${error}`)
    
        }
    }
    
    async login(email, password) {
        try {
            return await Account.createEmailSesson(email, password);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Appwrite error: login() :: ${error}`)
    
        }
    }
    
    async getCurrentUser() {
        try {
    
            return this.Account.get();
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Appwrite error: getCurrentUser() :: ${error}`)
        }
    
        return null;
    }
    
    async logOut(){
        try {
    
            return this.Account.deleteSessions();
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`appwrite :: logOut() : ${error}`)
        }
    }

}

const authService = new AuthService();

export default authService;\
```

Though I have provided all the code related to the file the error referring to, I don't really think the problem is more about the code. I think there is some problem in installing or importing the `appwrite`.

Comment: Please pos the error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error is also added in the text above. It is following

** Failed to resolve entry for package "appwrite". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.**

Comment: What version of the appwrite package do you have?